# What is wrong with this line of code? app.use('/node_modules',

Tags: node.js, express, npm, router

I am building a cryptocurrency gambling site and since last night I have been running into issues regarding my webserver and the game loading on it.

I had to remove the following line of code from my index.js because it was giving me `Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn)); No app.use('/',routes);`

Problem is, now that I've removed it, I get stuck in an infinite loading loop, you can see that here: http://185.141.61.20:3841/play

First thing I tried was clearing my cache and cookies on google chrome from the PC i was accessing the site with. Secondly I made sure my node modules were up to date, I don't really know where else to go from there as I am very new to a lot of this and the console is not throwing any errors, it's just not loading the game. I guess I'm asking, how can I make the following line of code work without giving me the above error?

```
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 });}
```

**INDEX.JS**

```
var fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var assert = require('assert');
var compression = require('compression');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var ioCookieParser = require('socket.io-cookie');
var _ = require('lodash');
var debug = require('debug')('app:index');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var config = require('../config/config');
var routes = require('./routes');
var database = require('./database');
var Chat = require('./chat');
var lib = require('./lib');

debug('booting bustabit webserver');

/** TimeAgo Settings:
 * Simplify and de-verbosify timeago output.
 **/
var timeago = require('timeago');
var timeago_strings = _.extend(timeago.settings.strings, {
  seconds: '< 1 min',
  minute: '1 min',
  minutes: '%d mins',
  hour: '1 hour',
  hours: '%d hours',
  day: '1 day',
  days: '%d days',
  month: '1 month',
  months: '%d months',
  year: '1 year',
  years: '%d years'
});
timeago.settings.strings = timeago_strings;


/** Render Engine
 *
 * Put here render engine global variable trough app.locals
 * **/
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, '../views'));

app.locals.recaptchaKey = config.RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY;
app.locals.buildConfig = config.BUILD;
app.locals.miningFeeBits = config.MINING_FEE/100;

var dotCaching = true;
if (!config.PRODUCTION) {
    app.locals.pretty = true;
    dotCaching = false;
}

app.engine("html", require("dot-emc").init(
    {
        app: app,
        fileExtension:"html",
        options: {
            templateSettings: {
                cache: dotCaching
            }
        }
    }
).__express);


/** Middleware **/
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compression());


/** App settings **/
app.set("view engine", "html");
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.enable('trust proxy');


/** Serve Static content **/
var twoWeeksInSeconds = 1209600;
if(config.PRODUCTION) {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
} else {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_new'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
    app.use('/client_old', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client_old'), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 }));
//    app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 });} crashes game
}


/** Login middleware
 *
 * If the user is logged append the user object to the request
 */
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    debug('incoming http request');

    var sessionId = req.cookies.id;

    if (!sessionId) {
        res.header('Vary', 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Cookie');
        res.header('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=60'); // Cache the logged-out version
        return next();
    }

    res.header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.header("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'");


    if (!lib.isUUIDv4(sessionId)) {
        res.clearCookie('id');
        return next();
    }

    database.getUserBySessionId(sessionId, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            res.clearCookie('id');
            if (err === 'NOT_VALID_SESSION') {
                return res.redirect('/');
            } else {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] Unable to get user by session id ' + sessionId + ':', err);
                return res.redirect('/error');
            }
        }
        user.advice = req.query.m;
        user.error = req.query.err;
        user.eligible = lib.isEligibleForGiveAway(user.last_giveaway);
        user.admin = user.userclass === 'admin';
        user.moderator = user.userclass === 'admin' ||
                         user.userclass === 'moderator';
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });

});

/** Error Middleware
 *
 * How to handle the errors:
 * If the error is a string: Send it to the client.
 * If the error is an actual: error print it to the server log.
 *
 * We do not use next() to avoid sending error logs to the client
 * so this should be the last middleware in express .
 */
function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {

    if (err) {
        if(typeof err === 'string') {
            return res.render('error', { error: err });
        } else {
            if (err.stack) {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] ', err.stack);
            } else console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR', err);

            res.render('error');
        }

    } else {
        console.warning("A 'next()' call was made without arguments, if this an error or a msg to the client?");
    }

}

app.use('/', routes);
app.use(errorHandler);

/**  Server **/
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketIO(server); //Socket io must be after the lat app.use
io.use(ioCookieParser);

/** Socket io login middleware **/
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    debug('incoming socket connection');

    var sessionId = (socket.request.headers.cookie)? socket.request.headers.cookie.id : null;

    //If no session id or wrong the user is a guest
    if(!sessionId || !lib.isUUIDv4(sessionId)) {
        socket.user = false;
        return next();
    }

    database.getUserBySessionId(sessionId, function(err, user) {

        //The error is handled manually to avoid sending it into routes
        if (err) {
            if (err === 'NOT_VALID_SESSION') {
                //socket.emit('err', 'NOT_VALID_SESSION');
                next(new Error('NOT_VALID_SESSION'));
            } else {
                console.error('[INTERNAL_ERROR] Unable to get user in socket by session ' + sessionId + ':', err);
                next(new Error('Unable to get the session on the server, logged as a guest.'));
                //return socket.emit('err', 'INTERNAL_ERROR');
            }
            socket.user = false;
            return next();
        }

        //Save the user info in the socket connection object
        socket.user = user;
        socket.user.admin = user.userclass === 'admin';
        socket.user.moderator = user.userclass === 'admin' || user.userclass === 'moderator';
        next();
    });
});


var chatServer = new Chat(io);

server.listen(config.PORT, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ', config.PORT);
});

/** Log uncaught exceptions and kill the application **/
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please check flow routes.js 
var router = express.Router(); 
router.post('/url', functionName); functionName must return response
 module.exports = router;
server.js include var routes = require('./routes'); and app.use('/', routes)

Comment: Im sorry, I don't fully understand what you are saying :/ my routes.js has ' var router = require ('express').Router(); '

Comment: Did you make router.js file separate and index.js? In index.js file include router.js file and make middleware it.  am I right? Or you did everything in one file index.js

Comment: Oh sorry, I have a route.js file and a index.js file, i included route.js file in index.js, i do not actually know how to make the middleware, Could you please help me if I link you my repo?

Comment: Just Remove this 2 line var router = express.Router(); and module.exports = router; from index.js file all will work fine.

Comment: That did not change anything unfortunately, if you check http://185.141.61.20:3841/play you will see it just sits on game loading forever, It started when i removed the aforementioned app.use code, I'm interested to know what i can replace that code with that wont cause issues

Comment: Please remove your above comment. It may help you out https://scotch.io/tutorials/keeping-api-routing-clean-using-express-routers

Comment: Can you not help identify what is wrong with this? app.use('/node_modules', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')), { maxAge: twoWeeksInSeconds * 1000 });}